# phpword document.xml error

Tags: php, xml, phpword

I had my script working well and it was populating data fine. I added two new field's in a table:

1. position_tasks
2. position_competences

Their data is pulled from a database. Now when I try to open the created word document I get prompted with a "Unspecified Error Location: Part: /word/document.xml, Line 2, Column:0"

So I open up the xml and on line 2 the whole document format. See Picutre
I notice that the data for the two new variables are giving displaying outside of this, Line 4 -19

Is it that they are list that's causing the problem? They should just text.

How would I fix that on my script

I set the Values as such:

```
$document->setValue('position_tasks', $positionTasks);
$document->setValue('position_competences', $positionCompetencies);
```

Is it because they are showing up as lists and I have stored it into a single variable?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14"><w:body><w:p w:rsidR="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="0035057A" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Title"/><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-GB"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7"><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-GB"/></w:rPr><w:t>Work Placement Letter</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRPr="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRDefault="00BA05D7" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>Dear Jutta Rinneranta</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">We are looking forward to meeting you soon at Foyle International.  Please find details of your work placement below.  </w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">(Please be advised that this information is provisional and is subject to change). </w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00BA05D7" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="00BA05D7" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr></w:p><w:tbl><w:tblPr><w:tblStyle w:val="LightList-Accent3"/><w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/><w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/></w:tblPr><w:tblGrid><w:gridCol w:w="2518"/><w:gridCol w:w="6724"/></w:tblGrid><w:tr w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidTr="00811211"><w:trPr><w:cnfStyle w:val="100000000000" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="0" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/></w:trPr><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:cnfStyle w:val="001000000000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="0" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/><w:tcW w:w="9242" w:type="dxa"/><w:gridSpan w:val="2"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="0035057A" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="32"/></w:rPr><w:t>Company Details</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidTr="0035057A"><w:trPr><w:cnfStyle w:val="000000100000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="1" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/></w:trPr><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:cnfStyle w:val="001000000000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="0" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/><w:tcW w:w="2518" w:type="dxa"/><w:tcBorders><w:right w:val="single" w:sz="8" w:space="0" w:color="3BAF4B"/></w:tcBorders></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="0035057A" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t>Name</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="6724" w:type="dxa"/><w:tcBorders><w:left w:val="single" w:sz="8" w:space="0" w:color="3BAF4B"/></w:tcBorders></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="00BA05D7" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:cnfStyle w:val="000000100000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="1" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>Nuprint</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidTr="0035057A"><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:cnfStyle w:val="001000000000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="0" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/><w:tcW w:w="2518" w:type="dxa"/><w:tcBorders><w:top w:val="single" w:sz="8" w:space="0" w:color="3BAF4B" w:themeColor="accent3"/><w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="8" w:space="0" w:color="3BAF4B" w:themeColor="accent3"/><w:right w:val="single" w:sz="8" w:space="0" w:color="3BAF4B"/></w:tcBorders></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="0035057A" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t>Address</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="6724" w:type="dxa"/><w:tcBorders><w:left w:val="single" w:sz="8" w:space="0" w:color="3BAF4B"/></w:tcBorders></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRDefault="00BA05D7" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:cnfStyle w:val="000000000000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="0" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>Unit 21 Springtown Ind. estate</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00772EEC" w:rsidRDefault="00772EEC" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:cnfStyle w:val="000000000000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="0" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>Springtown Road</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00772EEC" w:rsidRDefault="00772EEC" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:cnfStyle w:val="000000000000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="0" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>Derry</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00772EEC" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="00772EEC" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:cnfStyle w:val="000000000000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="0" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>BT48 0LY</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidTr="0035057A"><w:trPr><w:cnfStyle w:val="000000100000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="1" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/></w:trPr><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:cnfStyle w:val="001000000000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="0" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/><w:tcW w:w="2518" w:type="dxa"/><w:tcBorders><w:right w:val="single" w:sz="8" w:space="0" w:color="3BAF4B"/></w:tcBorders></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t>Website</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="6724" w:type="dxa"/><w:tcBorders><w:left w:val="single" w:sz="8" w:space="0" w:color="3BAF4B"/></w:tcBorders></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="00BA05D7" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:cnfStyle w:val="000000100000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="1" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>http://www.nuprintuk.com/</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidTr="0035057A"><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:cnfStyle w:val="001000000000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="0" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/><w:tcW w:w="2518" w:type="dxa"/><w:tcBorders><w:right w:val="single" w:sz="8" w:space="0" w:color="3BAF4B"/></w:tcBorders></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="0035057A" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t>Mentor</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="6724" w:type="dxa"/><w:tcBorders><w:left w:val="single" w:sz="8" w:space="0" w:color="3BAF4B"/></w:tcBorders></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="00BA05D7" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:cnfStyle w:val="000000000000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="0" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>${company_mentor}</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidTr="0035057A"><w:trPr><w:cnfStyle w:val="000000100000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="1" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/></w:trPr><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:cnfStyle w:val="001000000000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="0" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/><w:tcW w:w="2518" w:type="dxa"/><w:tcBorders><w:right w:val="single" w:sz="8" w:space="0" w:color="3BAF4B"/></w:tcBorders></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t>Description</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="6724" w:type="dxa"/><w:tcBorders><w:left w:val="single" w:sz="8" w:space="0" w:color="3BAF4B"/></w:tcBorders></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:cnfStyle w:val="000000100000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="1" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>${company_description}</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr></w:tbl><w:p w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="0035057A" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>${company_logo}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-GB"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7"><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-GB"/></w:rPr><w:t>Timetable</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7"><w:t>The normal hours of work are from 10:00 until 16:00. Note these are subject to change depending on arrangements with the host company.</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="0035057A" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-GB"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7"><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-GB"/></w:rPr><w:t>Dress Code</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="0035057A" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7"><w:t>Uniforms may be required</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00F06086" w:rsidRDefault="00F06086"><w:pPr><w:spacing w:after="200" w:line="276" w:lineRule="auto"/><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:eastAsiaTheme="majorEastAsia" w:cstheme="majorBidi"/><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:color w:val="3BAF4B"/><w:sz w:val="32"/><w:szCs w:val="28"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:br w:type="page"/></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-GB"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7"><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-GB"/></w:rPr><w:lastRenderedPageBreak/><w:t>Break &amp; Lunch Information</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0035057A" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>You</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7"><w:t xml:space="preserve"> will be m</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>ade aware of lunch and break facilit</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7"><w:t xml:space="preserve">ies at the host company during introduction. It is recommended to bring a packed lunch with you, as </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>facilit</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7"><w:t xml:space="preserve">ies may not always be available on site or </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">in the </w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7"><w:t>nearby area.</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-GB"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-GB"/></w:rPr><w:t>Your role at the host company</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRPr="00137738" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>Business Administration Assistant</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-GB"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-GB"/></w:rPr><w:t>Tasks</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00D358DD"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">These are some of the tasks that you </w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidRPr="00137738"><w:rPr><w:u w:val="single"/></w:rPr><w:t>may</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidRPr="00137738"><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>be required to undertake during your placement:</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRPr="00D358DD"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRPr="00F06086" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00D358DD"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr></w:p><w:tbl><w:tblPr><w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/><w:tblW w:w="9257" w:type="dxa"/><w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/></w:tblPr><w:tblGrid><w:gridCol w:w="676"/><w:gridCol w:w="8581"/></w:tblGrid><w:tr w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidTr="00096C08"><w:trPr><w:trHeight w:val="6402"/></w:trPr><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="676" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00D358DD"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="8581" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00D358DD"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00F06086"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr><w:t><p>Your duties would vary according to the department you worked in, but they might include:</p>

<ul>
 <li>dealing with enquiries by phone, in writing or in person</li>
 <li>research</li>
 <li>filing and photocopying</li>
 <li>producing and sending letters and emails</li>
 <li>updating computerised and clerical records</li>
 <li>acting as a secretary or personal assistant</li>
</ul>
</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00D358DD"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00D358DD"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00D358DD"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00D358DD"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00D358DD"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00D358DD"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00D358DD"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00D358DD"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr></w:p></w:tc></w:tr></w:tbl><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRPr="00F06086" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00D358DD"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00096C08" w:rsidRDefault="00096C08"><w:pPr><w:spacing w:after="200" w:line="276" w:lineRule="auto"/><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:eastAsiaTheme="majorEastAsia" w:cstheme="majorBidi"/><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:color w:val="3BAF4B"/><w:sz w:val="32"/><w:szCs w:val="28"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:br w:type="page"/></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-GB"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-GB"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">Competences </w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00D358DD"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">These are some of the professional competences that you </w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidRPr="00137738"><w:rPr><w:u w:val="single"/></w:rPr><w:t>may</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"> develop or acquire during your placement:</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRPr="00D358DD"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r></w:p><w:tbl><w:tblPr><w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/><w:tblW w:w="9303" w:type="dxa"/><w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/></w:tblPr><w:tblGrid><w:gridCol w:w="680"/><w:gridCol w:w="8623"/></w:tblGrid><w:tr w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidTr="00096C08"><w:trPr><w:trHeight w:val="8663"/></w:trPr><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="680" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00613EC9"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="8623" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRPr="00F06086" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00D358DD"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00F06086"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr><w:t><ul>
 <li>good spoken and written communication skills</li>
 <li>a polite, tactful and friendly manner</li>
 <li>accuracy and attention to detail</li>
 <li>good organisational skills</li>
 <li>the ability to work well as part of a team</li>
 <li>computer skills.</li>
</ul>
</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00613EC9"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00613EC9"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00613EC9"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00613EC9"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/></w:p></w:tc></w:tr></w:tbl><w:p w:rsidR="00D358DD" w:rsidRDefault="00D358DD" w:rsidP="00D358DD"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/><w:szCs w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRPr="00137738" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRPr="00137738" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/><w:rPr><w:i/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00137738"><w:rPr><w:i/></w:rPr><w:t>Please be advised t</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:i/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">hat these are subject to change </w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidRPr="00137738"><w:rPr><w:i/></w:rPr><w:t>depending on operations of the host organisation and also your capabilities and abilities.</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidRDefault="00FF4CD1" w:rsidP="00FF4CD1"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="both"/></w:pPr></w:p><w:sectPr w:rsidR="00FF4CD1" w:rsidRPr="00BA05D7" w:rsidSect="007F4FA9"><w:headerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId9"/><w:footerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId10"/><w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/><w:pgMar w:top="2528" w:right="1440" w:bottom="2552" w:left="1440" w:header="284" w:footer="403" w:gutter="0"/><w:cols w:space="708"/><w:docGrid w:linePitch="381"/></w:sectPr></w:body></w:document>
```

```html
$result13 = db_query('SELECT n.field_position_tasks_value FROM {field_data_field_position_tasks} n WHERE n.entity_id= :nid', array(':nid' => $positionID));
$record13 = $result13->fetchAssoc();
$positionTasks=$record13['field_position_tasks_value'];


$result14 = db_query('SELECT n.field_position_competencies__value FROM {field_data_field_position_competencies_} n WHERE n.entity_id= :nid', array(':nid' => $positionID));
$record14 = $result14->fetchAssoc();
$positionCompetencies=$record14['field_position_competencies__value'];


$filename = rand();
$file =  "GeneratedReports/".$filename.".docx";

$document = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor("PATH TO TEMPLATE");

$document->setValue('position_tasks', $positionTasks);
$document->setValue('position_competences', $positionCompetencies);



$document->saveAs($file);

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '.docx"');
$fsize = filesize($file);
 header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);

ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```

Thanks for the comments, I have inserted the XML and Section of Code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Show this code you talk about. And identify these 2 lines of code that stopped it working

Comment: Also paste the XML into your question and dont use external links, especially as that image does not show all the XML

Comment: what does your $positionTasks and $positionCompetencies variables contain? A string containing the complete html list structure? In that case you need to call the htmlspecialchars for those strings...

Comment: Excellent! got it working with `$document->setValue('position_tasks', htmlspecialchars($positionTasks));`  Thanks @ejuhjav